# My toggle button will not switch from left to right, I have coded in JavaScript and cannot find the bug?

Tags: javascript, html, css

First someone suggested it was a typo with my classList property and I made the necessary changes but it still is not working. I have js node downloaded but it still is not responding. Can anyone help? I cant yet find the bug i need some extra help. I have posted my css javascript and html files below
Here is my work..

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

function togglebtn() {
  btn.classList.toggle(".active");
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}
.hero{
    background: #1d2026;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;

}

nav{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    
}
nav .menu{
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

nav .logo{
     width: 500px;
     height: 200px;
     object-fit: none;
     padding-right: 50px;
     padding-bottom: 60px;


}
nav ul{
    flex: 1;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 20px;

}

nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 0 20px;
    
}
nav ul a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;

}
nav button{
    background: #efefef;
    height:30px ;
    width: 60px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    margin-right: 20px;

}
nav button span{
    display: block;
    background: #999;
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 2px;

}
.lamp-set{
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: 22%;
    width: 200px;

}
.lamp{
    width: 100%;

}
.light{
    position: absolute;
    top: 97%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 700px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.text-container{
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: 50%;
}
.text-container h1{
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;

}
.text-container p{
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 200;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 10px;

}
.emails{
    
    background: #00a8f3;
    padding: 14px 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    border-radius: 30px;

}
.active{
    background: turquoise;
}
.active span{
    background:#ffff ;
    margin-left: 31px;

}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
   <nav>
      <img src="menu.png" class="menu">
      <img src="ovlogo.png" class="logo">
      <ul>
         <li>
            <a href="">
               Home
         </li>
         <li><a href="">contact</li>
         <li><a href="">shop</li>
      </ul>
      <button type="button" onclick="togglebtn()" id="btn"><span></span></button>               
   </nav>
   <div class="lamp-set">
   <img src="lamp.png" class="lamp">
   <img src="light.png" class="light">
   </div>
   <div class="text-container">
   <h1>One Stop Shop.</h1>
   <p>Get the latest "as seen on" products and appliances that fit you and your everyday needs.We specialize in variety and identifying cunsumer sentiment to maximize the expirence with overviral, your online marketplace. </p>
   </div>
   <div class="emails">
   <a href=""style="text-decoration: none; color: #fff;">subscribe for emails</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We don't know what your `active` class in the stylesheet actually contains, so how do you expect us to be able to answer this? You need to provide a _proper_ [mre] when asking questions like this.

Comment: Adjust the question in the code so that it is a snippet. Ideally your js, html, css should all be in separate windows in the snippet. This will allow us to reproduce your current issue and help resolve it using your work.

Comment: The fact that your HTML is malformed could very much be contributing to this.  Have you noticed that *most of the page* is all one link, including the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the "**.**" from the toggle function className.

```js
function togglebtn() {
  btn.classList.toggle("active"); // remove the "." from the class name
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Something so simple you are the best!!!